# How to list and change elements from Python heapq without poping them?

Tags: python, heap

I have Python program which is sorting some tasks and executing them after certain delay.

Please check the code below

```
import heapq
import dateutil
from dateutil.parser import *
from datetime import *
from time import sleep
import time
h = []
now = parse("Sat Oct 11 17:13:46 UTC 2003")
today = now.date()
tup1=(dateutil.parser.parse('13:00 5.5.2018'), 10, 3, 'Job 1')
# push items into queue:
heapq.heappush(h, tup1)
heapq.heappush(h, (dateutil.parser.parse('14:00 5.5.2018'), 10, 2, 'Job 2'))
heapq.heappush(h, (dateutil.parser.parse('14:00 5.5.2018'), 1, 10, 'Job 3'))
heapq.heappush(h, (dateutil.parser.parse('13:30 5.5.2018'), 1, 3, 'Job 4'))

try:
    while True:
        if h:
            tuple=(heapq.heappop(h))
            print(int(tuple[2]))
            time.sleep(int(tuple[2]))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "exiting"
```

How could I modify something from existing list, like if I want to access the date value of Job 4, and how can I list them all without poping them?

Comment: `h` is just a normal list you can access the whole list without using `heapq` if you don't care about the order. However, modifying something could break the heap invariant.

Comment: I tried to modify them, and I got message "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment". I googled it and it looks like tuple is immutable. So can it be changed like in the example above?

Comment: You are not modifying it above. You may want to change your `while True:` to simply `while h:` then you can remove your `if` condition. BTW: you shouldn't name you variables after python types (`tuple`) because you hide the type functions.

Comment: I know I am not modifying it, but can I? Can I modify the item that is already in the heap. Can I change the date of Job4 for example?

Comment: Sure, you can change any item in the list, e.g. `h[2] = <new-tuple>` but you will need to call `heapify(h)` again to bring it back into the heap invariant. If it is the smallest (e.g. Job4), then you `heappushpop(h, <new-tuple>)`.

Comment: I need to change it by some identifier. I don't know if it is smallest or largest

Comment: Then you will need to search the list (`O(n)`) for the object and modify then `heapify()` (`O(n)`) - so relatively inexpensive. But do you really need a `heap`?